# Preventing DDOS attacks without collecting personal data?

Tags: databases, ddos, ids, denial-of-service

Could anyone suggest a system to prevent DDOS attacks without collecting personal data like i.p. addresses  ( or using anonymized data ) and be not deny access to an innocent user ?

Comment: There are so many ddos protections are available. You just need to config and enable it. NGFW provide comprehensive security

Comment: @Infra: Your comment does not actually address the question but essentially claims "there are things". And while NGFW provide some security it does in no way provide comprehensive security and specifically is usually not sufficient against DDoS attacks.

Comment: IPs are not PII in this context. Why do you want to avoid using IP for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible.

DDoS is a layer 3 issue, which means that IPs are the primary piece of data. Blocking DDoS higher up the stack will not be effective, and it is not possible to go lower in the stack. So, at some point, DDoS defences rely on IPs.

And if IPs are the dependency, then other realities come into play, like the fact that innocent people might have the same IP as an attacker. This is true for different users behind the same NAT.

You also appear to be of the impression that identifying users is somehow a part of DDoS defence. It isn't. Since this is a networking issue, and not an application issue, the connection between IPs and any user accounts is not made. Defences occur before the application.

So, not only is this not possible, but your requirements are unnecessary.

Comment: Is it going to be effective to SHA + pepper is just in case to deidentify it a bit . Will it weaken it ?

Comment: Your comment makes no sense and it lacks context or purpose. If you need to block an IP, you need the IP, not a hash of it. And a hash+pepper does not de-identify PII, even if the IP in this case was PII. You are not clear about what your purpose is, which makes me think you have a couple of XY Problems overlapping each other.